# Learning R Shiny: first app doesn't even read CSVs. What's going on?

Tags: r, shiny

Brand new R Shiny learner here. I only began yesterday. My first serious attempt to convert a console script into ShinyApp failed miserably. Function1 and Function2 in the code below are thoroughly tested in R console. Both work perfectly.

The app didn't seem to read the CSVs. When I clicked "Run app", the RStudio environment is completely empty, no dataframes, no functions, no variables, nothing. I only got a static panel with values of `output$inputA`, `output$inputB`, and `output$inputC`. In the box where the recipe is supposed to show, I saw "`Object Cake.input does not exist.`"

(Before every run I'd delete ".RData", except the first run. I assure you that's not the problem.)

What did I do wrong here?

Here's the code:

```
library(shiny)
server <- function(input, output) {

    setwd("/home/tcollar/Project")
    ##Avoid loading data every time,
    if (file.exists(".RData") ){
      load(".RData")
    } else {
      A.table <-read.csv(file = "/home/tcollar/CSV/CakeMix.csv")
      B.table <-read.csv(file ="/home/tcollar/CSV/Sugar.csv")
      C.table <-read.csv(file = "/home/tcollar/CSV/Ratio.csv")
      save(A.table, B.table, C.table, file=".RData")
    }
    
    output$inputA <- (renderPrint({input$CakeMix}))
    output$inputB <- (renderPrint({input$Sugar}))
    output$inputC <- (renderPrint({input$Ratio}))

    output$TheRecipe <- renderTable({ 
      ##  Function1 and Function2 read data from A.table, B.table, C.table and do math
      if (input$Sugar != "None")
        {
          Cake.input = Function1(input$CakeMix, input$Sugar, input$Ratio)
        }else
        {
          Cake.input = Function1(input$CakeMix)
        }
       ## Cake.recipe is a dataframe with 1 row and 10 columns, with header
    Cake.recipe <- Function2(Cake.input)
    }) 
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Cake baking recipe"),
    
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("This helps you calculate the recipes for cake-baking."),
      selectInput(inputId = "CakeMix", label = "CakeMix", 
        choices = c("Brand1", "Brand2", "Brand3", "Brand4"), selected = "Brand1"),
      selectInput(inputId = "Sugar", label = "Sugar", 
        choices = c("Cane", "Brown", "Substitute", "None"), selected = "None"),
      sliderInput(inputId = "Ratio", label = "Ratio", 
        min=0, max=100, value=5, step=0.1, round=1),
      submitButton('Submit')
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      h4("The brand of the cake mix is"),
      verbatimTextOutput("inputA"),
      h4("The sugar you selected is"),
      verbatimTextOutput("inputB"),
      h4("The ratio is"),
      verbatimTextOutput("inputC"),
      h4("Here is the recipe:"),
      tableOutput("TheRecipe")
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I cannot replicate the error given the information provided. There must be something in Function1 or Function2 that triggers the object does not exist error. But note that `load()` will not place variables into your global environment. It loads values into the environment where it was called, which in this case is your server function. You cannot view this environment from the RStudio environment pane. Nor can the pane update while the app is running because it is a blocking action.

Comment: Hi @MrFlick, thanks for checking my code. A couple of thoughts. 1. Function1 and Function2 are both fairly intricate. One or both can be incompatible with Shiny. I will do a thorough check tomorrow. The silver lining is at least my Shiny code is good.

Comment: 2. if the dataframes and variables are not loaded into RStudio environment pane, is there a way I can track them? I'm entrenched in R console programming. It's gonna be hard for me not to see them somewhere. It also makes debugging harder.

3. Any good debug tools for R Shiny?

Comment: The general rule is to only have as much code outside the server function as possible that's not dependent on any reactivity so you can easily test the functions outside the shiny environment. Only put stuff require for reactivity in the server function. What shiny sees shouldn't be different than what you see in the console for the most part. As far as debugging goes, check out this article: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/debugging.html

Comment: @MrFlick Confirmed -- it was the functions. Actually, both of them. I identified two hidden bugs in the functions. The Shiny App is running!

Comment: @tcollar, I am facing exactly the same issue, could you please let me know what are the hidden bugs?